# If Statement equivalent in Halide

Tags: if-statement, halide

Need help implementing if equivalent in Halide

```
if (current_pixel_mag > threshold) {
  mag = 65535;
  ed = 0;
}
```

I have tried Halide Select, but that is equivalent of ternary operator in C, and does not support multiple statements for given condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, the following code should do the job:

```cpp
Var x, y;

Func mag = ...;
Func ed = ...;

Expr threshold = ...;

mag(x, y) = select(mag(x, y) > threshold, 65535, mag(x, y));
ed(x, y) = select(mag(x, y) > threshold, 0, ed(x, y));
```

It's quite inefficient because of update definitions and it's difficult to schedule two functions in a single loop over `x, y`.

That said you could store multiple statements in a single function, then you could use [tuples](https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_13_tuples.html). There are another `select` function for tuples called [`tuple_select`](https://halide-lang.org/docs/namespace_halide.html#a8f04c3a60a6f50464ee6aca3d484ee3e):

```cpp
Func magAndEd;
magAndEd(x, y) = {mag(x, y), ed(x, y)};
magAndEd(x, y) = tuple_select(magAndEd(x, y)[0] > threshold, {65535, 0}, magAndEd(x, y));
```

Also, it might be possible to fold thresholding into initial definition of the `magAndEd`.